# Time spent in phases of cell cycle

Tags: cell-biology, mitosis, literature

I am looking for references to papers containing the time intervals spent in different phases of the [cell cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_cycle) (ej., G0, G1, S, G2, M for eukaryotes) for different cells. In particular, I am interested in E. coli and CHO (Chinese Hamster Ovary cells), but any reference to studies of this kind for any typical cell will be useful.

I'll accept an answer containing a representative sample of references to the literature on this subject. Preferably recent papers (since 2010).

If you can provide the times spent in each phase but don't have references at hand, that will also be useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the data for a few cell types:

```
Cell type   Total      G1      S      G2      M      Ref
----------------------------------------------------------
Neuro2a        9       2       5      1.5    0.5     [1]
Hela         16.2     7.7     7.2     0.8    0.5     [2]
A549          18       7      7.5     2.5     1      [3]
MCF7         21.3      9      9.3      2      1      [4]
CHO           15       6      6.8     1.2    0.65    [5]
```

The timescale is in hours.

---

References:

1. [De Laat et al. 1980](https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.77.3.1526)
2. [Kumei et al. 1989](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2693468)
3. [Orfanoudakis et al. 1989](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2752214)
4. [Taylor et al. 1983](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6871842)
5. [Harada and Morris 1981](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC369707/)

Comment: +1 Thanks. This is useful, but I am looking for recent papers mostly. If you provide some more recent references (from 2010, preferably reviews), I'll accept this answer. Also, do you have any data on CHO or NS0? And what are the units of time in this table (hours, days)?

Comment: its not a popular thing for researchers to reproduce old results... not sure you will find more recent ones.

Comment: @shigeta so you're saying that these measurements have not been significantly improved/corrected in 20 years?

Comment: Not definitively, but its quite possible.  I'm sure we could measure melting points and osmolarity better now, but I can't recall seeing someone spending their time to do it.  Science famously doesn't even try to reproduce some of their most important cancer research.  I wouldn't fault WYSIWYG if they can't be found.