# How does the zygote divide much faster than other cells?

Tags: cell-biology, embryology

Normally a cell has a mechanism that controls its division. As far as I know, it checks surface area and stuff like that to decide to go for mitosis or not.

However, this is not the case for a zygote. A zygote, after around ~14 days starts to divide rapidly and forms the blastula. What mechanism controlls this "rapid division"?
Why can zygote divide rapidly when it has not reached a high surface area or doesn't have enough mitogens to induce the cell division? Does the zygotes mini-cells have a cell cycle like other cells but they are really fast? Or do they just copy the DNA and divide rightaway?

And when I first saw the video of this stage, I was surprised. The DNA is a one long molecule; how fast do those replicators work?

Answer (score 1):

A zygote generally has a lot of nutrients, essential biomolecules like RNA and proteins and cytoplasmic organelles for rapid division. So the cell does not grow and divide but rather undergoes "[cleavage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleavage_(embryo))" (there is no G1 phase of cell cycle). However, it still undergoes DNA replication. And yes, DNA replication is fast because it is initiated at once from several parts ([origins of replication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_of_replication)) of the long DNA (it still takes a few hours<sup>†</sup> ).

---

<sup>†</sup> See:

- [Confusion about the duration of different phases of the cell cycle such as G1, G2 & S](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/80690/3340)
- [Time spent in phases of cell cycle](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/13703/3340)