# Does anyone know any statistics about the rate of cell division of malignant cells?

Tags: cancer, mitosis

I've tried to look online to find some statistical data about the rate of growth of any type of cancerous cells, but haven't been able to find any. Would anyone know an appropriate time period for a single cancer cell to divide? Obviously, this hugely varies with the stage of cancer and type etc., but I am looking for any acceptable figure correct to an order of magnitude.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/13703/3340) for some related information. Meanwhile, please also narrow down your question to a specific kind of cancerous cell so that the question is not broad. I don't know what is an order of magnitude in your case but the doubling time can vary from a few hours to more than a day.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks! 